# Qt: optimize the paint event

Tags: c++, qt

I am currently reading image from a decoder and paint each frame of it in a widget. 
This is what I am doing now:

```
 paintEvent(...){ 
    ...
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, false);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::HighQualityAntialiasing, false);
    QPixmap pmap = QPixmap::fromImage(glImage).scaledToWidth(width());
    painter.drawPixmap(0, (height() - pmap.height()) / 2, pmap);
    ... 
  }
```

However, I found it to be computationally expensive...
Is there any solution to this without using the OpenGL in Qt?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use QPainter::drawImage instead of doing manual conversion between image representation (QImage -> QPixmap). Refering to documentation it should still provide way to scale the image -"Note: The image is scaled to fit the rectangle, if both the image and rectangle size disagree.".

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is no need to scale your pixmap before painting. You can pass the desired width and height as an argument to `painter.drawPixmap`. This will scale the image while painting which is (probably) faster.

```
QPixmap pmap = QPixmap::fromImage(glImage);
int w = width();
// "scaledToWidth"
int h = w * pmap.height() / (double)pmap.width();
painter.drawPixmap(0, (height() - h) / 2, w, h, pmap);
```

Then, you could try to draw the image directly. Depending on which operating system you are using, this might be slower or faster.

On Windows, for example, `QPixmap` is internally represented by a `QImage` anyway. And therefore,  `QPixmap::fromImage` will basically create a  (possible unnecessary) copy of that image.

```
int w = width();
int h = w * glImage.height() / (double)glImage.width();
painter.drawImage(0, (height() - h) / 2, w, h, glImage);
```

If you draw the image directly, alpha blending can become quite expensive. So if possible, use a pixel format without alpha channel or with premultiplied alpha. *(In the premultiplied format the red, green, and blue channels are multiplied by the alpha component divided by 255.)* (See also: [QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied is your friend](http://tsdgeos.blogspot.de/2007/10/qimageformatargb32premultiplied-is-your.html)).

Bonus fact: That's basically what `QPixmap::fromImage` on Windows does. If you pass a `QImage` with alpha channel to that function, the internal `QImage` will be stored with premultiplied alpha to optimize render performance. [See source code](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/1051fdb87d302455c1a959fe89d0b04734dc4d6c:src/gui/image/qpixmap_raster.cpp#L386).